# Angular sequential $http requests of multiple elements in list?

Tags: angularjs

Say I have a list:

```
var mylist = ["a","b","c","d"];
```

I want to request data for each one of these like so and get the responses back in the same order.

```
var comeback = [];
getMyData()

function getMyData() {
  for (int i = 0; i < mylist.length; i++) {
    $http.get("http://myurl/" + mylist[i]).success(function(data) {
      results.append(data);
    });
  }
}
```

How can I make sure that the "comeback" list has all the responses based on "a", "b", etc. in the same order? What is the best way to write this?

Answer (score 0):

Chaining the promises will make them execute in series. Something like:

```
var results = [];
getMyData(0);

function getMyData(i) {
    return $http.get("http://myurl/" + mylist[i]).success(function(data) {
      results.push(data);
      i++;
      if(i < mylist.length) {
       getMyData(i);
      }
    });
}
```

Note: If you want to do more advanced validation and error checking, you would need to use `$q`.